# Angular project on Plesk

Tags: angular, passenger, plesk

Iv got this error when i refrech the site.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/vhosts/partyq.de/httpdocs/requestr/dist/requestr/app.js'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at Module.require (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at loadApplication (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
    at setupEnvironment (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:133:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js' ]
}

Node.js v18.17.0
```

what is the problem? can some one explain or help

I tried to search but i dont find anything helpfull

Comment: This looks like a path issue. In your script you need to check where /requestr/app.js is mentioned. It is obviously called with a relative path so it becomes appended to /requestr/dist, but it should actually replace /requestr/dist and not be appended. One way to solve this could be to use absolute paths, but it depends on how the requestr/app.js is formulated.